# docker is not finding DB in mongodb

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, docker, devops

I got this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined
> at /usr/src/app/backend/app.js:107:8
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
> at next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
> at Route.dispatch (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
> at /usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
> at Function.process_params (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
> at next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
> at /usr/src/app/backend/app.js:31:5
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

I have pulled the mongodb image `docker pull mongo:latest` and run it on port 27017, then I create the frontend image

```
    # Use an official Node.js image as the base
    # Use an official Node.js image as the base
    FROM node:14.20

    # Set the working directory
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app
    
    COPY package*.json ./
    COPY package-lock.json .
    
    RUN npm cache clean --force
    RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
    RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps
    
    # Copy the entire Angular project to the working directory
    COPY . .
    
    # Build the Angular app
    RUN ng build
    
    # Expose the Angular app's default port (adjust if necessary)
    EXPOSE 4200
    
    # Start the Angular app
    CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "4200"]
```

and then run `docker run -d -p 4200:4200 --name frontend-container --link backend-container frontend-image`

Next I create backend image

```
    # Use an official Node.js image as the base
    FROM node:14.20
    
    # Set the working directory
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app
    
    # Copy package.json and package-lock.json files to the working directory
    COPY package*.json ./
    COPY package-lock.json .
    
    # Clear npm cache
    RUN npm cache clean --force
    RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps
    
    # Copy the entire backend code to the working directory
    COPY . .
    
    # Expose the backend's default port (adjust if necessary)
    EXPOSE 3000
    
    ENV MONGODB_URL mongodb://localhost:27017/gymusers
    
    
    # Start the backend server
    CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Next I run `docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name backend-container -e DATABASE_NAME=mydatabase --link mongodb-container backend-image`.

I want to run my frontend angular, the backend nodejs, and want to create database name *gymusers* and table *users* .

Answer (score 0):

If your MongoDb is on your local machine as example, you cannot access it with "localhost:xxxx" inside a container. If the MongoDb is running in a container, so you say you do it, you need to use the containers ip address.

`docker inspect CONTAINERNAME`

(Were the CONTAINERNAME is your MongoDB container name) Then you see the ip of the MongoDB container.

A better approach is using **Docker Compose**. Yo you can create a `YAML` file which will build all your container easily and you can set a `network` in it. So you don't need the ip address, instead you can use the MongoDb containers name.
A minimal example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    networks:
      - app-network

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mongodb_data:
```

Read more about it [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

the **build** part of the frontend and backend is your "Dockerfile". The network binds all container in the same docker network. So in your app your MongoDB connection string can be: `mongodb://mongodb:27017/gymusers`.

The second "mongodb" will be translated to its containers ip address - automatically by docker.

Comment: is your posted file is for my project or its just an example

Comment: You can modify it. build -> context is the folder path of your frontend/backend. The other thinks should be work

Comment: still getting same error